# Generating row and column of a given nonogram-like table

Tags: python

What are nonogram tables?

> Nonograms, also known as Hanjie, Picross or Griddlers, are picture logic puzzles in which cells in a grid must be colored or left blank according to **numbers at the side of the grid** to reveal a hidden picture.

There are two kind of nonogram tables, ones with only one row and column, and kinds with multiple rows and columns. For simplicity's sake, I have assumed that nonogram table given has only one row and one column, and **5x5** only. That is why my table is only *nonogram-like*, a true nonogram table gives out two columns if a row is as if `colored-blank-blank-blank-colored`. But in my code if the nonogram table is like that, the column will be `2` instead of `1 1`.

Anyways, the code, in which I have assumed that blank spaces are 0 and painted spaces are asterisk. Keep in mind that blank space can be any character.

```
def nono_descriptor(given_string):
    number_of_lines = given_string.count('\n') #number of line breaks
    length_of_string = len(given_string) #length of the given string

    if number_of_lines != 4 and length_of_string != 29:
        raise Exception("You need exactly four line breaks and 25 characters!") #throw exception if conditions don't match

    rows_split = [] #list that contains each line split
    columns_list = [] #list that contains columns
    rows_list = [] #list that contains rows

    list_of_lines = given_string.split('\n') #split the string by line break

    for each_line in list_of_lines:
        rows_split.append(list(each_line)) #populate rows list with split up characters
        columns_list.append(each_line.count('*')) #populate columns list with the number of asterisks in each column

    for i in range(5):
        temp_list = [row[i] for row in rows_split]
        rows_list.append(temp_list.count('*'))

    print (columns_list, rows_list)


nono_descriptor('0*0*0\n***00\n****0\n*0*0*\n****0')
```

Would love to hear your opinions.

Again, don't mistake this code as a nonogram table generator. It only generates a table similar to that of a nonogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Size of the grid

> ```
>     raise Exception("You need exactly four line breaks and 25 characters!") #throw exception if conditions don't match
> ```

Using a generic `Exception` is bad practice. What should the calling code look like if it want to handle such failure? Something like

```
with open('da_file.txt') as picture:
    pic = picture.read()
try:
    descr = nono_descriptor(pic)
except Exception:
    print('Not the right size')
else:
    print(descr)
```

probably. Meaning that if *anything* goes wrong, it would be treated as if the input was not as expected.

You should at least use a more specific kind of exception (such as `ValueError`) or roll your own:

```
class BadGridSizeError(Exception):
    pass

def nono_descriptor(...):
    ...
    raise BadGridSizeException("...")
```

But why limit at 5×5 grids in the first place, why not let the user provide a grid with the size they like? It is easy to check that the grid is square and keep the size for further operations instead of hardcoding the value 5:

```
def nono_descriptor(given_string):
    list_of_lines = given_string.splitlines()
    grid_size = len(list_of_lines)

    assert all(len(row) == grid_size for row in list_of_lines), "Square grid expected"

    rows_split = [] #list that contains each line split
    columns_list = [] #list that contains columns
    rows_list = [] #list that contains rows


    for each_line in list_of_lines:
        rows_split.append(list(each_line)) #populate rows list with split up characters
        columns_list.append(each_line.count('*')) #populate columns list with the number of asterisks in each column

    for i in range(grid_size):
        temp_list = [row[i] for row in rows_split]
        rows_list.append(temp_list.count('*'))

    print (columns_list, rows_list)
```

Using an `assert` here is also more friendly to the user that can deactivate such checks (using the `-O` or `-OO` switch on the command line) when they know that their input is good.

You don't even need to restrict the grid to being square, you can have m×n grids if you check that each row is the length of the first one:

```
def nono_descriptor(given_string):
    list_of_lines = given_string.splitlines()

    assert list_of_lines, "At least one row expected"

    grid_size = len(list_of_lines[0])

    assert all(len(row) == grid_size for row in list_of_lines), "Rectangular grid expected"

    rows_split = [] #list that contains each line split
    columns_list = [] #list that contains columns
    rows_list = [] #list that contains rows


    for each_line in list_of_lines:
        rows_split.append(list(each_line)) #populate rows list with split up characters
        columns_list.append(each_line.count('*')) #populate columns list with the number of asterisks in each column

    for i in range(grid_size):
        temp_list = [row[i] for row in rows_split]
        rows_list.append(temp_list.count('*'))

    print (columns_list, rows_list)
```

## Counting by rows and columns

You can easily get the count of `'*'` using a list-comprehension rather than using `append()`:

```
columns = [row.count('*') for row in list_of_lines]
```

You can argue that it's better to build `row_split` in the meantime while iterating over `list_of_lines`… But you don't need that list. The only thing you use it for is to be able to index the `i`th column in each row. But you can do that exactly the same way using plain strings because `list(my_str)[i]` is exactly the same as `my_str[i]`. Meaning you can write:

```
columns = [row.count('*') for row in list_of_lines]

rows = []
for i in range(grid_size):
    tmp = [row[i] for row in list_of_lines]
    rows.append(tmp.count('*'))
```

However there are two improvements possible. The first one being using a list-comprehension:

```
rows = [[row[i] for row in list_for_lines].count('*') for i in range(grid_size)]
```

The second one being to use `zip` instead of trying to manually do its exact job:

```
rows = [colum.count('*') for column in zip(*list_of_lines)]
```

One more advantage using `zip` is that it will stop producing columns when the shortest row has been exhausted. Meaning you don't even need to check that the grid is rectangular anymore:

```
def nono_descriptor(given_string):
    lines = given_string.splitlines()

    columns = [row.count('*') for row in lines]
    rows = [column.count('*') for column in zip(*lines)]

    print(columns, rows)
```

## print vs return

Printing a result within a function that perform some computations is bad practice. Your function can't be reused in a different context. What if I wanted to iterate over some files and use your function to append the various counts at the end of said file. Well I can't, because you `print` the result, so I can't do anything with it:

```
def nono_descriptor(given_string):
    lines = given_string.splitlines()

    columns = [row.count('*') for row in lines]
    rows = [column.count('*') for column in zip(*lines)]

    return columns, rows
```

Your use case should now be

```
print(nono_descriptor('0*0*0\n***00\n****0\n*0*0*\n****0'))
```

which might seem more work here, but it lets you reuse you function way more easily.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question, how can we compress this syntax: `for i in range(n): \n for j in range(k)` inside a list comprehension? Meaning, a list comprehension with two or more variables?

Comment: @CodesInTheValley `[stuff_using(i,j) for i in range(n) for j in range(k)]` But you most probably want to iterate over the content rather than over indices, something like `[stuff_using(letter) for row in grid for letter in row]`